# Deleting photos rom within an app

Tags: iphone

Is it possible to delete photos from the camera roll from within an iphone app?

Does iOS allow for modifications to system assets from within an application?

Comment: This question would feel more at home in http://apple.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot delete or modify existing photos. Only add new ones.

Comment: So I currently use thumbnails from the ALAssets of the read in photos.  What would be a better way to store captured pictures in my app and then read them in later to fill a tableview with thumbnails like I currently do?

Comment: What does that have to do with your original question?